# array JS to php codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I need to send an array of java script to php, this is the idea that I have made but it does not work, if you can help solve the problem or find another way to do it I would appreciate it.
The idea is to reload the entire page again.

I have problems sending a JSON to a controller via AJAX, the JS alert works and the JSON shows me, but the controller is not receiving the data.

creation of 'actualizar':

```
var actualizar = new Object();
function myButton_onclick(x,id) {
   if(x.style.backgroundColor=='rgb(255, 114, 144)')
{
    x.style.backgroundColor='rgb(90,237,247)';
     actualizar[id]=1;

}else{
    x.style.backgroundColor='rgb(255, 114, 144)';
     actualizar[id]=0;

}
console.log(actualizar)
return false;
}
```

view:

```
$id= array('id' => 'x' );
echo form_open("cursos/guardarmalla",$id);?>
<div align="center"><?php echo form_submit('','Guardar Malla',"class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"");?></div>
<?php echo form_close()?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#x').submit(function(){
      var aux = JSON.stringify(actualizar);
      $.ajax({
        type  :'POST',
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        dataType: "json",
        data   : aux
    });
  alert(aux);

  })
})
</script>
```

controller:

```
function guardarmalla(){

    $datos= $this->input->post('aux');
    $deco=json_decode($datos,true);
    echo "Los datos recibidos son".$deco;

}
```

I regret having the variables in Spanish. I'm from Chile and in stackoverflow in Spanish I had no answer

**EDIT**

I think the problem is that ajax does not cause the driver function to run

**EDIT EDIT**

Investigating arrives at the conclusion that AJAX is not necessary, since I want to reload the whole page again, but I do not know how to send an Array or JSON they are the "submit" button to PHP

Comment: What is the value of `actualizar` ? Show HTML form code

Comment: It is an associative array. for example:Actualizar['INC100']=1
, Actualizar['INC101']=0. The value will always be 0 or 1

Comment: @franco.pina Could you check $_POST array in your controller? If array empty than you have problems on your frontend.

Comment: @Pasha 
effectively, the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ajax` in js you need to correct code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type  :'POST',
        url: $(this).attr("action"),
        dataType: "json",
        data   : {'aux' : aux}
    });
```

It corrected structure of json variable

Also instead `alert(aux);` add `return false;`. It is prepent of html form submit.

Comment: it did not work :(

Comment: Can you show errors?

Comment: no, the page only shows  'Los datos recibidos son'.

maybe it can be some WAMP configuration

Comment: insert `var_dump($this->input->post('aux'))` at the start of controller method. Let see structure of json

Comment: the page shows "null"

Comment: What show your `alert` ? Please show it

Comment: the alert if it shows the aux variable.
for example:
localhost says: {"INC211": 0, "INC212": 0}

Comment: Also instead `alert(aux);` add `return false;`. It is prepent of html form submit.

Comment: if I place return false; and alert (aux); The same thing is still happening, if I only put 'return false;' the page does not change

Comment: Using ajax is for dont change page. Why you use ajax? You can simply send values from `form` and page will be reloaded

Comment: the array ' actualizar' is in javascript, I did not find another way to send it to php. If there is another way to do it, it would be good